# How to upgrade Chromedriver to match chrome version in Ubuntu

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, upgrade, ubuntu-18.04

So i already have chromedriver version 89.0.4389.23 installed in my VM and google-chrome version is 90.0.4430.212. I have to update chromedriver. Do i need to remove the current chromedriver to install new one ? or is there any work around ?

If i have to delete chromedriver completely and install again, how do i delete it ?

I had used the following commands to install chromedriver :

```
1.sudo apt-get install unzip
2.wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/89.0.4389.23/chromedriver_linux64.zip
3.unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
4.chmod +x chromedriver
5.sudo mv -f chromedriver /usr/local/share/chromedriver
6.sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
7.sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2, python 3.6.9

Comment: Looks good to me, I do basically the same. mv will replace the old version. Any problem?

Comment: @ken these are the commands he used originally to install chromedriver (notice the version number). is there a way to update chromedriver with whatever the latest version is without having to manually look for that link on chrmium downloads?

Comment: @PSSolanki the OP asked if he needed to delete in order to install the new version. No, mv will overwrite it. But I think people may find their way to this question because it is tiresome to have to sync Chrome and Chromedriver manually. My application does not absolutely require the latest Chrome but when I learn of a new release - every couple months ? - I wait until I'm in the mood, then do as described in the OP's question. See https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager for an automated approach.

Comment: @ken [Here is a shell script](https://bitbucket.org/pssolanki/workspace/snippets/KprEer) script (the commands were taken from an SO answer on similar question). I just put them together in a shell script script.

Comment: @PSSolanki thanks, I like that and I'll try it. However, I almost always update Chrome along with any other packages found by Webmin or Ubuntu. When I am not 'in the mood', I update everything else but Chrome. Your script seems like an improvement but would end up being one manual command replacing another. You assume that the latest chromedriver version matches the latest Chrome, which is reasonable I guess. More ideal would be to *detect* an update of Chrome (no idea how), get the version (or not), then upgrade chromedriver. I'm guessing again, but that might help a lot of people!

Comment: @PSSolanki I should add that this Selenium application is critical for our business. We aggregate content from 500+ sites each day and human editors in various time zones do the rest. So I choose to update Chrome and Chromedriver and reinitialise the application manually and when it is convenient. But it would be cool to link the Chrome and Chromedriver upgrades if it could be done reliably.

Comment: hey @ken appreciate the inputs. I would certainly try to take those into consideration and see if I can improve the shell script. About it being manual: schedule a cron job for every month (just for example) and it will do the update without manual intervention. I would not recommend this for a critical business just yet since it is experimental and I do not have a whole lot of observations about its behavior but certainly seems like a good starting point.